# Is there Entity Framework performance difference for multiple item search?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there Entity Framework performance difference for following two query executions:

1.

```
int[] ints = { 1,2,3,4,5 }

var results = context.Books.Where(b => ints.Contains(b.Id));
```

2. 

```
var results =  context.Books.Where(
    b => b.Id == 1 || b.Id == 2 || b.Id == 3 || b.Id == 4 || b.Id == 5);
```

`ints` array count may be 10, 20 or 30.

Is there any performance difference between these queries? (I am using oracle and entity framework 6)

Comment: Compiller converts first to the second or maybe second to to the first. Depends on sql version.

Comment: I came across this in past and it convert this into in query for SqlServer but @Serge is right too that for some provider and version it convert it to Or.

Comment: "Is there any performance difference between these queries?", why don't you measure? Predicting how the different layers of rewriting and optimizations will work is quite difficult and may depend on the actual implementations. Measuring is probably way easier.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the answer would yield different results depending on provider and SQL version.

Why not race your horses to find out? Log the SQL output generated by EF using [`Database.Log`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.log?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) on your `DbContext` and then compare the output of the two queries:

```
context.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

The `Log` property can be set to a delegate for any method that takes a `string` as input.

If performance proves to be an issue you can time/benchmark the queries using something as simple as a `StopWatch` or a library like [`BenchmarkDotNet`](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).

Aside: For your scenario of a maximum of 30 items, I believe performance differences would be negligible, if any. I would go with the first query purely for readability.